# Не читает данные из массива $_SERVER

Tags: php

Есть такая проблема на сервере, любое обращение в php скрипте к массиву $_SERVER не возвращает ничего. После любого редактирования и сохранения этого php скрипта, то ровно 1 раз всё работает и данные возвращает. 
К примеру вот такой вот код

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

1 раз возвращает GET, после обновления страницы уже ничего не возвращает.
Отредактировал(просто давил пустую строку) и пересохранил скрипт и снова 1 раз нормально.
И такая проблема не на одном сайте а как минимум на двух, один самопальный, другой на wordpress. На втором из за этого не возможно отправлять комментарии, так как там проверятся метод отправки(POST).
Не знаю уже в какую сторону копать.

Comment: а зачем POST проверять через $_SERVER? Не проще ли $_POST использовать? что пишется в логах сервера по вашим запросам?

Comment: На счет проверки POST через $_SERVER это уже вопрос к авторам вордпресса. Проблема в том что из $_SERVER не возвращаются ни какие данные, просто пустой результат. На счет логов вечером посмотрю.

Comment: До логов пока не добрался.
Проверяю вот такой код

`<?php
 ini_set('display_errors',true); 
 echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`
Первый раз как обычно выдает юзер агент, далее выдает _Notice: Undefined variable: _SERVER in ..._

Answer (score 2):

Вобщем проблема вроде решена.
Всё дело в параметре `auto_globals_jit` в `php.ini`
Временно добавил в php строчку `ini_set('auto_globals_jit',false);`, работает как надо.